# Deriving Feynman rules from Renormalized Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, path-integral, feynman-diagrams

In the context of Renormalized Pertubation Theory, Peskin & Schroeder says:
The Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu\phi_r)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi_r^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi_r^4 + \frac{1}{2} \delta_Z(\partial_\mu\phi_r)^2 -\frac{1}{2}\delta_m\phi_r^2-\frac{\delta_\lambda}{4!}\phi_r^4
$$
gives the following set of Feynman rules:
------------>------------ = $\frac{i}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$
------------X------------ = $i(p^2\delta_Z-\delta_m)$
and the two 4-vertices.
The question is: Why look the Feynman rules for the first and the fourth term of the Lagrangian look so different? I believe the answer is connected to the fact that one has to bring the kinetic term of the Lagrangian to its canonical form $\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu\phi_r)^2$ and has to interpret everything else as (possibly momentum dependent) vertices. How does this look in formulae?

Comment: This issue is explained [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/18529/deriving-feynman-rules-from-renormalized-lagrangian?show=18606#a18606), the trick is to properly define what is the perturbed and what is the unperturbed part of the Lagrangian when doing perturbation calculations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the counterterms in renormalized $\phi^4$-theory with power two in fields give vertices and not propagators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335476/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are derivatives in interaction terms treated differently from derivatives in the kinetic term?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/374395/)