Why do we treat quadratic counterterms as interactions rather than free terms?
For example, in QED (or any other theory containing particles with spin 1/2) the renormalized countains
$$
\mathcal{L} \subset \bar{\psi} (i \displaystyle{\not}\partial -m)\psi + \bar{\psi} (\delta_2 i \displaystyle{\not}\partial- (\delta_2 + \delta_m) m)\psi,
$$
where $\delta_2$ and $\delta_m$ are quadratic counterterms associated to the field and the mass, respectively.
My question is, why do we treat the quadratic counterterms as interactions, rather than accounting for them in the propagator, which is
$$
\dfrac{i}{\displaystyle{\not}p - m},
$$
and not
$$
\dfrac{1}{Z_2}\dfrac{i}{\displaystyle{\not}p - m_0},
$$
where $\psi_0 = \sqrt{Z_2}\psi$ and $m_0 = Z_m m$ are the bare field and mass and $Z_i := 1+\delta_i$?

Would you get the result you want if you did it differently? I'm not really sure there's any answer here besides that's how the counterterm procedure is defined because that results in useful answers.

You can treat it as a free term also, if you want. The result is the same.

possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335476/84967

An interesting thing is I think you can do Feynman diagrams on even the free propagator terms and treat those as interactions. But the Feynman diagrams would just have two edges with a single vertex. So if you treat the free part as just the derivative part and treat the m term as an interaction, it probably works out to something that "slows the propagation" or something. Interestingly this kinda explains why we only use quadratic terms for the free propagator.
